# Wordpress: wpdb->insert VERSUS wpdb->prepare(wpdb->query("INSERT

Tags: php, database, wordpress, sql-injection

I am wondering if wordpress' insert function also adds slashes to data. If it doesn't it would seem that the prepare query method would be better to prevent against SQL injection. I tried looking the issue up in there codex/api; however, it seems undocumented. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wordpress uses [ezSQL](http://www.woyano.com/jv/ezsql) to query the database. Technically, it is not an abstraction layer but it does take away some of the boilerplate code. ezSQL has a function `escape` so I assume that Wordpress would always call the escape function before executing a query. But to be certain you would have to take a look at the source code.

This is how you escape a string in Wordpress:
    `$safe_string = $wpdb->escape($unsafe_string);`

Answer (score 12):

This question is a little old and the codex may have been updated since it was asked.  Both `wpdb->insert()` and `wpdb->prepare()` provide the same level of safety regarding SQL escaping of input data.

The [codex states](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#INSERT_rows) that the both the column and data values provided to the insert method should be raw, not SQL escaped.

I also took a quick look at the source to confirm.  The implementation for the insert method uses `wpdb->prepare()`.

Comment: +1. No longer doing wordpress stuff; however, this answer rocks. I remember not knowing what prepare did at all or why all the examples were using it.