# When should I use $wpdb->prepare, if at all?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a hard time figuring out if I should be using `$wpdb->prepare` on my database queries in WordPress to prevent things such as SQL injection.

The [$wpdb Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) shows some examples using the $wpdb->prepare function, and other examples not using it.

Also, in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16040644/849987) on StackOverflow, someone mentioned that a function such as `$wpdb->insert` has the same level of safety as using `$wpdb->prepare`. But what about other `$wpdb` functions such as `$wpdb->get_var` or `$wpdb->query`?

**When should I use `$wpdb->prepare`, if at all?**

Some of my (simplified) `$wpdb` class and function usage looks like this:

---

**Example 1:** `$wpdb->insert`

```
$wpdb->insert(
                'special_posts', 
                    array( 
                        'title' => $title,
                        'selftext_html' => $selftext_html,
                        'selftext' => $selftext,
                    ), 

                    array(
                        '%s',
                        '%s',
                        '%s',
                    )
            );
```

---

**Example 2:** `$wpdb->get_results`

```
$wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM special_posts WHERE selftext_html = '$value'");
```

---

**Example 3:** `$wpdb->get_var`

```
$wpdb->get_var("SELECT title FROM special_posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
```

---

**Example 4:** `$wpdb->query`

```
$wpdb->query('TRUNCATE TABLE special_posts');
```

Comment: Take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24988867/when-should-i-use-prepared-statements/24989031

Comment: Example 2 is precisely why you use prepared statements. Short answer: **YES**.

Comment: So just to be 100% sure. WordPress's `$wpdb` functions do not automatically prepare SQL statements to prevent SQL Injections? Or is it that some of them do, and others don't?

Comment: Technically `$wpdb` is not a function, it's an object made by `wpdb` class. And as far as I know, no it doesn't. You must always sanitize the db query if you are entrusting a user to run it.

Comment: Also related: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/1287812)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand - the methods those have placeholders for query parameters (`$wpdb->insert()`, `$wpdb->update()`, `$wpdb->delete()`) don't need the `$wpdb->prepare()` method, and they are already safe.

But the others - those don't have placeholders, need additional sql escaping.